# Can't exit while loop

Tags: c, loops, break, infinite

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0,j=0,direction=0,k=0,l=0,ix=0,jx=0,mov0=1,mov1=1,mov2=1,mov3=1;
    char cl='B';

    printf("Enter the size of the maze: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&i,&j);
    char maze[i][j];

    for(l=0;l<j;l++)
    {
        for(k=0;k<i;k++)
        {
            maze[k][l]='.';
        }
    }

    i=0;
    j=0;
    maze[i][j]='A';
    //maze[0][0]='A';
    srand(time(NULL));
    //starts moving through maze
    /*for(jx=0;jx<l;jx++)
    {
        for(ix=0;ix<k;ix++)
        {
            printf("[%c]",maze[ix][jx]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }*/


    while  ((mov0!=1 && mov1!=1 && mov2!=1 && mov3!=1) || (cl!='Z'+1 ) )
    {
        /*//reset space(positions above 1)
        spaces=1;*/
        //generates direction
            direction=rand()%4;
            printf("%c %d\n",cl,direction);
            /*for(jx=0;jx<l;jx++)
                            {
                                for(ix=0;ix<k;ix++)
                                {
                                printf("[%c]",maze[ix][jx]);
                                }
                                printf("\n");
                            }*/
            switch(direction)
            {
                //up
                case 0: if((j-1)>0 && maze[i][j-1]=='.' && mov0==1)
                            {
                                maze[i][j-1]=cl;
                                cl++;
                                j--;
                            } else {
                                mov0=0;
                                break;
                            }

                            break;
                //down
                case 1: if((j+1)<l && (maze[i][j+1]=='.' && mov1==1))
                            {
                                maze[i][j+1]=cl;
                                cl++;
                                j++;
                            } else {
                                mov1=0;
                                break;
                            }

                             break;
                //left
                case 2: if((i-1)>0 && (maze[i-1][j]=='.' && mov2==1))
                            {
                                maze[i-1][j]=cl;
                                cl++;
                                i--;
                            } else {
                                mov2=0;
                                break;
                            }

                            break;
                //right
                case 3: if((i+1)<k && (maze[i+1][j]=='.' && mov3==1))
                            {
                                maze[i+1][j]=cl;
                                cl++;
                                i++;
                            } else {
                                mov3=0;
                                break;
                            }

                            break;

            }

    }
    for(j=0;j<l;j++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<k;i++)
        {
            printf("[%c]",maze[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code is supposed to walk through an array and fill each spot it goes to with a letter from the alphabet and if there are no available spots to go it has to exit and print the array as is. (can't go to the same cell twice).

edit #2:

I also tried this way:

```
switch(direction)
        {
            //up
            case 0: if((j-1)>0 && maze[i][j-1]=='.')
                        {
                            maze[i][j-1]=cl;
                            cl++;
                            j--;
                        } else if((maze[i+1][j]!='.') && (maze[i-1][j]!='.') && (maze[i][j-1]!='.') && (maze[i][j+1]!='.')){

                            flag=0;
                            break;
                        }

                        break;
            //down
            case 1: if((j+1)<l && (maze[i][j+1]=='.'))
                        {
                            maze[i][j+1]=cl;
                            cl++;
                            j++;
                        } else if((maze[i+1][j]!='.') && (maze[i-1][j]!='.') && (maze[i][j-1]!='.') && (maze[i][j+1]!='.')){

                            flag=0;
                            break;
                        }

                         break;
            //left
            case 2: if((i-1)>0 && (maze[i-1][j]=='.'))
                        {
                            maze[i-1][j]=cl;
                            cl++;
                            i--;
                        } else if((maze[i+1][j]!='.') && (maze[i-1][j]!='.') && (maze[i][j-1]!='.') && (maze[i][j+1]!='.')){

                            flag=0;
                            break;
                        }

                        break;
            //right
            case 3: if((i+1)<k && (maze[i+1][j]=='.'))
                        {
                            maze[i+1][j]=cl;
                            cl++;
                            i++;
                        } else if((maze[i+1][j]!='.') && (maze[i-1][j]!='.') && (maze[i][j-1]!='.') && (maze[i][j+1]!='.')){

                            flag=0;
                            break;
                        }

                        break;

        }

}
```

the flag variable replaces all 4 mov# variables. Still not exiting while loop.

edit #3 fixed what @SomeProgrammerDude pointed out. still not exiting.

Comment: With a debugger you can step through your code, line by line, while monitoring variables and their values. Using a debugger this way is an efficient and quick way to find problems such as yours. Being able to use a debugger is a crucial skill for any programmer, no matter if it's just for hobby or for work.

Comment: So what exactly is the question? (Apart from the fact that you don't actually `break` from the `while` loop, only from the `switch` `case`s)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude which debugger can you recommend me?

Comment: @UnholySheep the problem is that when all mov# variables are 0 , it's not exiting the while loop.

Comment: The logical OR operator uses [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). If the left hand side is true, the right hand side is not evaluated. So as long as `cl != 'Z' + 1` is true, you will not check the `mov?` variables.

Comment: As for debugger it depends on your platform (OS) and environment (command-line or IDE).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i tried testing for the mov# variables first and it still does not exit the while loop, any other things I can try?

Comment: So you want to exit the loop if all those `mov#` variables are equal to zero? First of all you should be specific about it. Second of all, all those variables are initialized to zero to begin with Lastly, inside the loop you only set *two* of the variables to zero, the other two to one.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry those were really stupid mistakes, i fixed it, but it's still not exiting.

Comment: Your `while` condition checks if your `mov` variables are `!=1`, not `!=0`

Comment: `i`, `j`, `mov0`, `k`, `mov2`, `l`, `jx`, `mov1`, `ix`, `cl`, `mov3` ... and not a single function, all code on one big pile of .... well, I guess a non exiting while loop is appropriate punishment for that ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
    while  ((mov0!=1 && mov1!=1 && mov2!=1 && mov3!=1) || (cl!='Z'+1 ) )
```

should be

```
    while  ((mov0!=1 && mov1!=1 && mov2!=1 && mov3!=1) && (cl!='Z'+1 ) )
```